# Stop s.recv when data ends

Tags: python, sockets, file-handling

I have a python script that essentially sends logs from the server to the client, however I don't know how long the logs will be.

Once the client recieves the logs, I have to then write them to a file,

Client code looks like so:

```
    with open('raw.txt', 'wb') as f:
    while True:
        logsreturned = s.recv(512)
        print(logsreturned)
        if logsreturned == '':
            break
        if not logsreturned:
            break
        f.write(logsreturned)
        logsreturned = ''
```

What ends up happening however is the last part of the logs doesn't get written to the file, and the client ends up hanging, I can't figure out why

I've tried the above two break clauses to see if I can get the client to break out of the while loop once done, however it's still not writing the last less than 512 bytes to the file

Comment: Your code is not properly formatted. The client will 'hang' if the peer never closes the connection. You need a better protocol. Are the log messages formatted in some way, such as always always ending in a line feed (`\n`) character?

Comment: The client can either close the connection or it can send a conventionally agreed sequence (or single character such as EOT) to indicate that there's no more data to follow

Comment: A single character is unnecessary and requires a full-blown escape protocol in case it occurs in messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv` will return whenever data are available, no matter if these are the last data or not. There is no concept in TCP (assuming this is what you use)  of *"last data"*, there is only the concept of connection shutdown/close. And `recv` will return with `''` when connection is shutdown/closed. Outside of that `recv` will block until new data come in or the connection is closed/shutdown.

But this should not matter, since you write to the file whenever new data come in. The likely problem is instead that these data are still buffered until you close the file. To prevent this either explicitly flush the data after each write or disable buffering [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
with open('raw.txt', 'wb', buffering = 0) as f:
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, the client now writes all of the data to the file, however it still hangs and doesn't break from the while loop

Comment: @E.V.A.: as I said, the client returns with `''` in `recv` when the server has closed or shutdown the connection. If the server simply stopped sending while keeping the connection open this can not be distinguished from a temporary pause or end of data. Note that I still assume TCP here even though this is not clear from your code. With UDP it is different: there is no connection close but there is also no "no more data" - one has to use timeouts instead and assume that the server is done if no data arrived for some time.